# CakePHP "Agree TOS" Checkbox Validation

Tags: validation, cakephp

I am trying to have a Checkbox "Agree TOS".

If the Checkbox is **not checked**, I want to put out a Flash Message.

How do I do this?

**My View:**

```
<?php   
        echo $form->create('Item', array('url' => array_merge(array('action' => 'find'), $this->params['pass'])));
        echo $form->input('Search', array('div' => false));
        echo $form->submit(__('Search', true), array('div' => false));
        echo $form->checkbox('tos', array('label' => false, 'value'=>1)).' Agree TOS'; 
        echo $form->error('tos');
        echo $form->end();
?>
```

**My Model:**

```
var $check = array(
            'tos' => array(
               'rule' => array('comparison', 'equal to', 1),
               'required' => true,
               'allowEmpty' => false,
               'on' => 'index',
               'message' => 'You have to agree TOS'
               ));
```

Comment: Your rules array should be `$validate`, not `$check`, I believe.

Comment: Maybe overkill, but you can also leverage a [Confirmable Behavior](http://www.dereuromark.de/tag/confirmable/).

Answer (score 17):

This seems working for me. Hope it will help.

In model:

```
            'tos' => array(
                'notEmpty' => array(
                    'rule'     => array('comparison', '!=', 0),
                    'required' => true,
                    'message'  => 'Please check this box if you want to proceed.'
                )
```

In view:

```
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('tos', array('type'=>'checkbox', 'label'=>__('I confirm I have read the <a href="/privacy-statement">privacy statement</a>.', true), 'hiddenField' => false, 'value' => '0')); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

basically, you add the rule "notEmpty" for this field to the `public $validate` array of the model.
this way an error will get triggered on `Model->validates()` if the checkbox has not been checked.

maybe some overhead in your case, but if you happen to use it more often try a DRY (dont repeat yourself) approach. you can also use a behavior for this to use this clean and without tempering too much with the model/controller:

```
// view form
echo $this->Form->input('confirmation', array('type'=>'checkbox', 'label'=>__('Yes, I actually read it', true)));
```

and in the controller action

```
// if posted
$this->Model->Behaviors->attach(array('Tools.Confirmable'=>array('field'=>'confirmation', 'message'=>'My custom message')));
$this->Model->set($this->data);
if ($this->Model->validates()) {
    // OK
} else {
    // Error flash message here
}
```

1.x:
https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/1.3/models/behaviors/confirmable.php

for 2.x:
https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tools/blob/2.x/Model/Behavior/ConfirmableBehavior.php

3.x: https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tools/blob/master/src/Model/Behavior/ConfirmableBehavior.php

details:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/07/05/introducing-two-cakephp-behaviors/

Answer (score 1):

Model

```
'agreed' => array(
       'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('comparison', '!=', 0),//'checkAgree',
            'message' => ''You have to agree TOS'',
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'required' => true,
            'last' => true, // Stop validation after this rule
            'on' => 'signup', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
```

View

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('agreed',array('value'=>'0'),array('type'=>'checkbox', 'label'=>'Agree to TOS')); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need try save it into your model to catch your tos rules. I should do something like =

```
if(!$mymodel->save()){
 // catch error tos.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$this->ModelName->invalidFields()` returns an array of fields that failed validation.

You could try and search this for the `tos` field, and output a message if the key exists.

~untested (I'm not sure off the top of my head the exact structure of the `invalidFields` return array.

```
$failed_fields = $this->ModelName->invalidFields();

if(array_key_exists('tos', $failed_fields)) {
    $this->Session->setFlash('Please accept the terms and conditions');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't even have to have validation rule for tos, just check that at the controller before saving the data.

> ```
> if($this->data['Model']['tos']==1){
>      // save data
>   }else{
>      //set flash
>   }
> ```